# How to create a curved semi-opaque background without using an image?

Tags: html, css, background

I need to create a semi-transparent background in CSS similar to this image:

[image]

I honestly don't even know where to start - obviously rgba(0,0,0,0.7) will come into play here, but I'm not sure what I need to be looking at to start this. Something with border-radius? I can't seem to find any other questions similar to this to get an idea of where to start...

Comment: Off hand, I can't think of anything that would work other than a hacky workaround. Example: https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/6347ae776eb9eb5397463a2bfcc1c4df

Comment: Radial gradient!